# Oracle: Sqlldr throwing error with 'truncate into table' ctl file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Sqlldr throwing error while loading just one specific file which has `truncate into table` specified in its `ctl file`.
Is a `append into table` statement also required in the `ctl file` after the truncate statement to load data into the database table?

Rest other ctl files having just the `append into table` statement, are getting loaded fine into db tables.

Just this one throwing error. The associated table doesn't have any referential integrity constraint as mentioned in the `oracle docs` that in which case sqlldr throws error with truncate into table clause of ctl file.

Comment: If we only knew **which error** ...

Comment: please post .ctl file

Comment: “In a dark place we find ourselves, and a little more knowledge lights our way.” – Yoda